# AS3 Concurrency Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, concurrency

Consider an actionscript program, such that whenever a download is complete (and a complete event occurs), a value is pushed into an array.

If there can be many simultaneous downloads, could the array push function fail? For example, a complete event occurs, the function to push a new value is initialized, but before the function terminates, another complete event occurs, and a second push function is started before the first one is done, therefore messing up the array somehow.

Could such problem occur?

Comment: The event model works as a queue. That is, if you dispatch two `COMPLETE` events at the same time, they will be queued and processed one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the push method from the Array class, no that is not a concern.

If you were rolling your own array class & implementing a push method in some strange fashion, then you might worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you described is not possible in Flash. Flash is entirely single threaded, unless you are using a `Worker` (which, if you are, you should know the answer to your question already). What this means is that Flash cannot execute more than one thing at a time (a "thread" is a term referring to a portion of a processor that can execute code. Generally, it is 1-2 per CPU core). Even with an async event, it has to wait until there is a gap in execution before it can dispatch and other code can run. So, basically, it is impossible in Flash for two events to fire simultaneously or for any two processes to run at the same time.

And to address another point in your question, the execution of one long line of code is never interrupted. So let's look at this code:

```
var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
l.load(new URLRequest("http://google.com"));

for (var i:uint = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    trace("let's mess with the console");
}

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    trace("complete");
}
```

So we have an async load of Google, which should be quite quick. It won't, however, be quick enough to finish before that loop begins (which is in the microsecond range). It doesn't matter, though, because the event could not dispatch until the loop ends. So, assuming the debugger/IDE doesn't crash from there being a million logs pouring in (literally), that `COMPLETE` event would appear at the very end of the console, after the 1 million "let's mess with the console" messages. That loop could take 30 seconds and that load could take 120ms. It doesn't matter. Nothing can stop that loop from finishing and nothing can happen until it does.

So, to paraphrase, events fire when there is an opening in execution. As Marty mentioned, the Event system behaves like a queue. When there is a gap in execution, it will dispatch an event. When there is another gap, keeping in mind that the code in the handler for a listener for the previous event has to finish before that gap can occur, the next event fires.

Comment: Thanks. I think another test could be, which I'm going to try, is having the loop you wrote start after an event, to see if it finishes before any output by a second event is produced.

Comment: The only time I believeit should stop executing the current thread of code is if you dispatch an event *while* running that thread of code. so if you were dispatching an event *during* that loop, it should execute handlers before the next line of code hits, though don't quote me on that. That is because the app gets a chance to dispatch before the end of the code.